# Change terminal in visual studio code by iTerm2 with Powerlevel10k

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, configuration, iterm2

I'm trying to change my VScode terminal. I have followed this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070).

My iTerm terminal has been changed perfectly : 
[image]

I tried to edit my settings.json files in VScode like this :

```
{
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome Regular'"
}
```

But i got this different result :

[image]

I can't understand why the parameters are not the same and some images do not pass in VScode.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Finally, the `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily"` points out (apparently) the non-ASCII font. The settings.json file from Visual Studio Code should be :

```json
{
  "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue with the format in vscode. Adding the font as above is the answer, that finally solves the problem.

Comment: I think the default way of defining shell changed to `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"`